# Unable to get the doc id from firestore even doc is present in the firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am storing chat messages in the Firestore below is the code

```
 static Future<void> _addMessageToChat(
    String receiverId,
    ChatMessage message,
  ) async {
   ;
    await firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection('chat')
        .doc(receiverId)
        .collection('messages')
        .add(message.toJson());
```

The problem is while retrieving the doc ids from the chat collection.
As you can see in the below image, in the chat collection there is a doc
[image]

I am retrieving all the docs that are present in the **chat collection** below the flutter code for that:

```
Future<List<UserModel?>> getChatUsers() async {
    String currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    print('current user-id : $currentUserId');

    CollectionReference chatCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(currentUserId)
        .collection('chat');
    try {
      // Read chat data
      QuerySnapshot chatSnapshot = await chatCollection.get();

      if (chatSnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        // Extract chat IDs from the snapshot
        List<String> chatIds = chatSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.id).toList();
        print("Chat IDs: $chatIds");
      } else {
        print("No chat data found for the current user.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print("Failed to read chat data: $error");
    }
```

When I ran this code even though there is doc is present I was unable to get the doc ID from the chat collection. and also  I have double-checked the current user ID. Below this output
[image]

But if add any document to the chat collection manually. I am able to retrieve those doc ids from the chat collection
[image]

[image]

In below output image clearly illustrates that only manually added document IDs are visible, while those added by the app remain absent. Additionally, upon inspecting the Firestore database, I noticed that document IDs inserted by the app are stored in italic format, whereas the document IDs I added are stored in regular, non-italic style.
[image]

Even I have tried by passing doc id, still  it was able to retrieve docs in the chat collection  which are added by the app.

```
 void test() {
    var documentId = "tV0WkME1ulfF9RmPVy0ZCeyytbf1";
    String currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

    var documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(currentUserId)
        .collection("chat")
        .doc(documentId);

    documentReference.get().then((documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        // Document exists, handle the data here.
        var data = documentSnapshot.data();
        print("Document Data: $data");
      } else {
        // Document does not exist.
        print("Document does not exist.");
      }
    }).catchError((error) {
      // Handle errors.
      print("Error retrieving document: $error");
    });
  }
```

Output:
[image]

I would like to understand the reasons behind the issue I am experiencing with Firestore. Can you please help me identify what might be causing this problem or if there is something I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Look at how your documents are displayed in an italic font: This means that these documents are only present as "container" of one or more sub-collection but that they are not "genuine" documents.